# When using the chrome driver with Karate UI the driver.send command is not working

Tags: karate

I found the following tip on the Karate wiki that I wanted to use to get the unreachableUrl entry on a navigated page.

https://intuit.github.io/karate/examples/ui-test/#devtools-protocol-tips

When I run the command below I get an error about a cast.  I copied the sample exactly so I'm lost as to what the issue may be.

> javascript evaluation failed: driver.send({ method: 'Page.getFrameTree' }), Cannot cast jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.JO4 to com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsMessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was it!  I needed to upgrade to 0.9.6!  Thanks for the help and thanks for building a truly great framework!  I'm currently testing an Oauth workflow and needed to login to the IDP and the combination of Karate and Karate UI makes this seamless as 1 test I can use to test end to end!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure a `driver` has been summoned first

```
* driver 'https://google.com'
* driver.send({ method: 'Page.getFrameTree' })
```

If still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I created a new scenario and ran just those two lines and got the issue still.  I will follow the steps to submit an issue.  Just high level I'm using Karate 0.9.5 and Java jdk1.8.0_251.

Comment: @PBMax there it is. please use 0.9.6