# Chrome Driver with Karate 1.0.1 does not get frame tree

Tags: karate

I previously posted the question below which was resolved by upgrading Karate to 0.9.6.

[When using the chrome driver with Karate UI the driver.send command is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63715490/when-using-the-chrome-driver-with-karate-ui-the-driver-send-command-is-not-worki)

Now when I upgrade to Karate 1.0.1 the code that previously worked in 0.9.6 no longer works.
I checked the docs at the link below and it hasn't changed.

https://intuit.github.io/karate/examples/ui-test/#devtools-protocol-tips

When running the code below I don't get the frameTree back that I expect even though the driver output shows the frameTree I want:

```
  Scenario: Get Frame Tree
    * driver 'https://google.com'
    * def frame = driver.send({ method: 'Page.getFrameTree' })
    * print frame
```

Here is the actual output:

> 17:01:26.738 [main] DEBUG c.intuit.karate.driver.DriverOptions - >> {"id":7,"method":"Page.getFrameTree"}

> 17:01:26.749 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] DEBUG c.intuit.karate.driver.DriverOptions - << {"id":7,"result":{"frameTree":{"frame":{"id":"EF7B9A896E378D2847F3A5FD6647353E","loaderId":"74EA753CFFDB150AE371D4CC442E0B8C","url":"https://www.google.com/","domainAndRegistry":"google.com","securityOrigin":"https://www.google.com","mimeType":"text/html","adFrameType":"none","secureContextType":"Secure","crossOriginIsolatedContextType":"NotIsolated","gatedAPIFeatures":["SharedArrayBuffersTransferAllowed"]}}}}

> 17:01:26.750 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] {
> "id": 7,
> "method": null
> }

Is this a bug with 1.0.x?  I tried 1.0.1RC5 and I saw the same behavior.

Update to comment below:

I'll take a look but on first pass I don't even know what I'm looking at :) This is what I did which may have worked but was unsupported.  I need to get the URL from a page that isn't resolvable.

```
Scenario: GetUnreachableURL
    * string frameTree = driver.send(karate.toMap({ method: 'Page.getFrameTree' }))
    * print frameTree
    # headless chrome doesn't return chrome-error on unreachableUrls
    * def unreachableUrl = driver.url == 'chrome-error://chromewebdata/' ?  karate.extract(frameTree, 'unreachableUrl=(.+?)(?=,|})', 1) : driver.url
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to update this issue that this indeed was a bug and has been fixed in 1.1.0.

https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1690

Thanks Peter for your support.

Answer (score 0):

This may need you to contribute code and help, it sounds you are doing something we don't support.

The Chrome communication was re-factored in this commit: https://github.com/intuit/karate/commit/9600031f17d7a81509368d6da36c24de3e945e36

And just to make iframes work, there is a global variable set which is applied to all messages sent to Chrome, and perhaps the `send()` command is not considered. May I request you to contribute ? We have an easy to follow developer guide: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide

Comment: I'll take a look but on first pass I don't even know what I'm looking at :) This is what I did which may have worked but was unsupported.  I need to get the URL from a page that isn't resolveable.     I updated the question with the code I created to do so.  I may just need to expose unreachable URL as a property if I'm going to update the framework.  Maybe have a property called "driver.unreachableUrl" ?

Comment: @PBMax that's really hard to understand. another option is please follow this process or replicate: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/examples/ui-test

Comment: Sorry about that.  These comments don't format well and I actually updated my original question with the code that I am actually trying to get to work again.  The issue is if you go to a url that is not resolvable you will get a chrome-error://chromewebdata value returned if you try to get the url via driver.url.  My solution was to get the page frame to parse out the unreachable url.  I'll look into submitting a project to make it easy to reproduce.  The original scenario for get frame tree will reproduce with http://localhost as the url.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  It seems that this update removed the Result from the conversion to a Map. I added the code locally to test it fixed my problem. 
 Why was this change needed/done? 
 How can we get this fixed? 
 
 putting these lines back fixes the issue:              if (result != null) {
            map.put("result", result);
        } 
 https://github.com/intuit/karate/commit/8f7d6e03604374a85fe7b8d52c81a23c2a45cace#diff-446634215c4ea0b238ab34920e7693aef931e0af453293a7cefd11119093a666L217

Comment: I submitted this as an issue here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1690